# Wrong header in unnumbered chapter

Tags: header-footer, chapters

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

How to remove/fix the header "CONTENTS" in unnumbered chapter Acknowledgments?

Comment: You could also checkout https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/

Answer (score 8):

Just simply add the command `\chaptermark{Chapter name}` after `\addcontentsline`, this should work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\chaptermark{Acknowledgments}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about removing the header entirely from unnumbered chapter?

Comment: For removing the header look into page styles.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\frontmatter`  and `\mainmatter` instead of doing stuff by hand.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Acknowledgment}
\lipsum
\chapter{Prolog}
\lipsum
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```